# Left Click to Inspect Element While Dev Console is Open

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I used to have a setting in my chrome dev console that allow me to inspect any element I left clicked on so long as my dev console was open to the elements tab. I needed to reinstall chrome and doing so removed this feature. Any help to get it back would be great.

Comment: There's no such option, AFAIK, so the change must have been caused by something else. For example, the element may have been already removed from DOM after it was printed in console.

Comment: You may be referring to the Inspect mode, which when clicked, user can use the left click to select the element to inspect it in the Elements tab.